# Issue with shape key making

Tags: shape-keys

So I've been trying to make some shape keys involving the lips of my character's head. However, when I attempted to do so using proportional editing-smooth, I'm encountering an issue: If I try to move the upper lip only, the lower lips move along with the upper lip. I've tried with different proportion radio but the issue still persists. Are they merged?

I've shared the file below. Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

https://pasteall.org/media/2/c/2ccabc3f4a36abe2ebfd075a9e11c9eb.blend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *Proportional Editing* option, you need to enable the *Connected Only* option, this way only the connected vertices will move along the ones you've selected:

[image]

[image]